# WAP_PUSH_DELIVER Intent never sent by Android system

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions, mms

I spent 5 hours attempting to make a custom MMS Broadcast receiver work. I googled and searched here at Stackoverflow a gazillion of seemingly duplicate threads but non of the workarounds or proposed solutions.

A few random debugging notes:

- The app is set as default SMS app and all permissions were granted.
- Verified that RCS is disabled through Google's Messenger.
- The DUT is a Pixel 3 XL with latest software updates.
- Tested many 3P SMS/MMS apps, almost all aren't able to receive MMS either, however, [Pulse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xyz.klinker.messenger&hl=en) does. Pulse's developer provides an Open Source MMS library. I tried leveraging this library without success. The core problem seems to be that `WAP_PUSH_DELIVER` Intents are not sent to my application.
- Decoded the Pulse app to have a look at its `AndroidManifest.xml` and try a few different changes in mine. No success.
- Test MMS were sent with Google Voice account via legacy Hangouts and from other Android phones via various carriers.
- SMS can be received without problems both `SMS_RECEIVED` and `SMS_DELIVER` (if the app is the default SMS one).
- `WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED` events are received if the app is ***not*** the default SMS one
- `WAP_PUSH_DELIVER` events are not received if the app ***is*** the default SMS one
- Installed [Intent Intercepter](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/de.k3b.android.intentintercept/) and ran `$ adb logcat | fgrep -i intent` to verify if any permission problems are logged. None are.

MmsReceiver:

```
public class MmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("MMS Received: " + intent.getAction());
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".SmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name=".MmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".HeadlessSmsSendService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Needless to mention, the message is not logged in Logcat.

Answer (score 2):

[Make your app the default SMS app](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)

> On Android 4.4, only one app can receive the new SMS_DELIVER_ACTION
>   intent, which the system broadcasts when a new SMS message arrives.
>   Which app receives this broadcast is determined by which app the user
>   has selected as the default SMS app in system settings. Likewise, only
>   the default SMS app receives the new WAP_PUSH_DELIVER_ACTION intent
>   when a new MMS arrives.

it looks your app isn't the default *default SMS app*. therefore, you are not permitted to listen for incoming broadcasts.

something you need is to navigate user to select your app as default.like as official doc says:

```
public class ComposeSmsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        final String myPackageName = getPackageName();
        if (!Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this).equals(myPackageName)) {
            // App is not default.
            // Show the "not currently set as the default SMS app" interface
            View viewGroup = findViewById(R.id.not_default_app);
            viewGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Set up a button that allows the user to change the default SMS app
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change_default_app);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent =
                            new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
                    intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, 
                            myPackageName);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // App is the default.
            // Hide the "not currently set as the default SMS app" interface
            View viewGroup = findViewById(R.id.not_default_app);
            viewGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

And also, [WAP_PUSH_DELIVER_ACTION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html#WAP_PUSH_DELIVER_ACTION) highlights that

> This intent will only be delivered to the default sms app

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, the app is set as default SMS app. This answer unfortunately doesn't help.

Comment: @BasicCoder  i mentioned "it looks your app isn't the default SMS app" it's not definitely target problem.but i think so.

Comment: Not sure what code you want to see considering that the app basically consists exclusively of a manifest and bunch of empty receivers...

Comment: @BasicCoder "WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED events are received if the app is not the default SMS one" &
"WAP_PUSH_DELIVER events are not received if the app is the default SMS one". can you explain these two more in your question ? and also what exactly you want.